# Higher-Order Side Channel Security and Mask Refreshing: linear function?

Tags: algorithm-design, side-channel-attack, dpa

I currently read about this paper:
https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/359.pdf

and I wanted to implement Algorithm 4 / Algorithm 5 on my own. There is one thing I cannot understand: where does function g come from (used in Algorithm 4)? It is said to be a $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's any $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear function you want it to be.

That is, those two algorithms are generic ways, given a linear $g$ and a threshld (secret-shared) value $x$, to compute a threshold version of $x \times g(x)$ (where $\times$ is $GF(2^n)$ field multiplication).

Comment: First of all: thank you so much for this answer...sometimes I feel like I'm the only pirson into that topic at all. Secondly, can you give an example?

Comment: As an example, you might use that primitive several times to generate a threshold implementation of the AES SBox; the hard part of that (for a threshold implementation) is computing $x^{254}$

Comment: This means, as suggested in the paper, I can plug that into the algorithm for computing $x^{254}$